# What are the risks involved in updating pip?

Tags: python, pip

Every once in a while there's an update to pip. Does upgrading pip (usually) break anything, such as venv?

Comment: To the close-voters, how does this have "many valid answers?" (quote from https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) I'm not sure I can "[break] the question into multiple questions or [focus] on a specific part of the problem."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update `pip`, you update it for the version of Python you're updating it for. So, no, updating `pip` shouldn't generally break your virtual environments, provided you update within the virtual environment.

However, it's of course possible you're using a virtual environment that accidentally relies on some problematic behaviour of an old version of `pip` and you may break its capability to correctly (re)install the environment.